# How to display link after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I want to create a page that provide link after clicking the submit button...
for example,

1)wedding

2)engagement

3)birthday

all of 3 items is checkbox button. 
then there is a textbox to enter the budget. after clicking submit button, i want a hyperlink show up according to the package that already I have wrote in the javascript. so how to display hyperlink in javascript, that will show in the page...?

i hope anyone can help me with this. thank you.

> function send()
>         {
>             var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkwed');
>            var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('chkeng');
>             var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
>
> ```
>               if (checkbox.checked=='chkwed')
>               {
>                    if (document.form1.text1.value>1000 && document.form1.text1.value <1499 )
>                 { 
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 //document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Package W1 and W2";
>                 document
>
>                 }
>                 else if (document.form1.text1.value > 1500 && document.form1.text1.value <2698)
>                     {
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Package W3 and W4";}
>
>                 else if (document.form1.text1.value > 2699 )
>                     {
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Package W5 and W6";}
>                 else
>                     {
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = " No Package ";
>                     }
>               }
>               else if(checkbox1.checked=='chkeng')
>                   {
>                    if (document.form1.text1.value<1199 && document.form1.text1.value >799 )
>                 { 
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Package E1 and E2";
>                 }
>                 else if (document.form1.text1.value > 1200 && document.form1.text1.value < 1599 )
>                     {
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Package E3, E4 and E5";}
>                 else
>                     {
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = " No Package ";
>                     }
>                   }
>              else
>                  {
>                      if (document.form1.text1.value<699 && document.form1.text1.value >599 )
>                 { 
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Package B1 and B2";
>                 }
>                 else if (document.form1.text1.value > 999 && document.form1.text1.value < 1399 )
>                     {
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Package B3 and B4";}
>                 else
>                     {
>                 alert('Your package is:');
>                 document.getElementById('txtName').value = " No Package ";
>                     }
>                  }
>
>   }
>   </script>
> ```

this in javascript function

> Wedding
>
> ```
> <input type="checkbox" name="chkeng" id="chkeng" onClick="show2()"/>
> <label for="chkeng">Engagement </label>
>
> <input type="checkbox" name="chkbirth" id="chkbirth" onClick="show3()"/>
> <label for="chkbirth">Birthday</label>
>
>
> </form>
> ```

i want after click submit button, then the hyperlink will show up in the page...near textbox button for recommended package..

Comment: Have you written anything so far?

Comment: show us the code than the description blah blah....

Comment: What is this 'package' you've written? Are you referring to a function? If so, please post it on JSFiddle and include the link here to assist us in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks on any checkbox button , you can use Ajax to get the particular url.

$.get({
       url:'/engagment',
      success: function(){}
      });

and replace the content in the success handler.

Comment: Cool, the OP will take forever to work out `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`. ;-)

Comment: $ is jquery you can use any library ajax jquery or native to get the page.